# Arrange FireStore Cloud Functions in multiple files

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have noticed a strange behaviour in FireStore Cloud Functions that if try to break my code up into separate files, I start to get this error:

```
info: Worker for app closed due to file changes.
```

I just created a simple express server and hosted it in a cloud function and was emulating it locally as described here. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&t=244s

I even wrote tests for the same. Everything was working fine until I split the source code of my express app into individual routes (contained in separate `.js` files).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that message means is that the emulator noticed when a code file changed, and performed a hot reload of that code.  Note that it's just an "info" level message, not an error and not even a warning.

If your project is not working the way you expect, then edit your question with the symptoms you're observing, along with the code.

Comment: I wrote jest tests which were hitting the express routes. But after splitting, those very tests started failing abruptly. Sometimes 2 tests passed, sometimes 6 and sometimes 4 and this message was getting printed.

Comment: That sounds like something different than what you originally posted.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion but those jest tests were just trying to hit the API. I was not using cloud functions shell to test my https function.

Comment: OK, so, maybe you should edit your question to accurately describe what you're doing and what the problem is?